# How to insert arbitrary JSON response to mongodb collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, mongodb, bson

I have described the model in the following way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feed extends Model
{
    protected $collection = 'feeds';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $appends = ['id'];
    protected $hidden = ['_id'];
    protected $fillable = ['feed_content'];
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

I want to save the content of the API response in database logs:

```
    $feed_info = $driver->getAdvertiserFeed();
    $feed_id = new Feed;
    $feed_id->feed_content = $feed_info;
    $feed_id->save();
```

The connection to MongoDB is configured in this way:

```
    'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'feeds'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test'),
        'options' => [
            'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'), 
        ],
    ],
```

But when I try to execute the second piece of code, I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize()
must be of the type array, string given, called in
/home/pavel/Projects/axonite/vendor/laravel/framework/
  src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 853

at /home/pavel/Projects/axonite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php:138
    134|      *
    135|      * @param  array   $values
    136|      * @return string
    137|      */
  > 138|     public function parameterize(array $values)
    139|     {
    140|         return implode(', ', array_map([$this, 'parameter'], $values));
    141|     }
    142|
```

What exactly do I do wrong? How to fill JSON in a collection in a more correct manner with getting a document id back? I want to save it in the relational database for retrieving it later. Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: install [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) because right now that error is useless. Get a real stack trace so you can see where in _your_ code things went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't support noSql database like mongodb and others..

You need to use PHP methods for the specific database or you can use this ORM package: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

This package will enable all the ORM functionality same as RDBMS.

Comment: Ummm...yes it does! https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that MongoDB configuration was trying to get credentials for Mongo auth from MySQL settings in .env file:

```
'mongodb' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'feeds'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test'),
    'options' => [
        'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'), 
    ],
],
```

Replacing it with static values has solved the problem:

```
'mongodb' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' =>  27017,
    'database' =>  'feeds',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'test',
    'options' => [
        'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'axonite'), 
    ],
],
```